Environment.getProperty a Map<String, String>from properties (using SpEL)
I'm trying to retrieve a Map<String, String> value from my application.properties using Spring Boot Configuration.
In my class I have the following:
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app.connection")
@Getter
@Setter
public class ConnectionProperties {

    private int groupId; // this is correctly loaded from application.properties

    @Value("#{${app.sftp.basic.defaultFields}}")
    private Map<String, String> defaultFields; // this too

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;


In my application.properties, I have this:
app.connection.groupId=123
app.sftp.basic.defaultFields={authType: 'basic'}

The @Value-annotated field defaultFields correctly gets populated by the application.properties "app.sftp.basic.defaultFields" key. This correctly contains the expected Map value, containing an entry with "authType" as key and "basic" as value.
However, the key to retrieve this Map value with will be dynamic, so using the @Value annotation doesn't seem like an option. So further down the class I have the following line:
Map<String, String> defaultFields = environment.getProperty(defaultFieldsKey, Map.class);

But this doesn't work and throws the following error:
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<?, ?>]

The @Value annotation uses SpEL which enables the magic to correctly convert the value to a Map, but I haven't found the same possibility using Environment.getProperty.
How can this be achieved? Or will I just have to read the value as a String and write my own custom String-Map conversion?

You can use Spring's Binder to read all of the properties in a given key as a map:
public class Test() {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    public Map<String, String> readProperties() {
        return Binder.get(environment).bind("yourkey", Bindable.mapOf(String.class, String.class))
    }
}

I got this idea from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/14874#issuecomment-645536598 and it works great.
